# Capistrano 3 set optional variable - exists() method not working

Tags: ruby, capistrano3

I'm writing a Capistrano deploy lib task and am trying to set an optional variable.. i.e. a default value that is only set IF it's not been set in the user's deploy.rb.

I found the following for Capistrano 2:

```
if !exists?(fetch(:optional_var))
  set :optional_var, 'optional value'
end
```

But in Capistrano 3 I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'exists?' for main:Object` error when running it.

I've tried `defined()` but that seems to always return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check how `capistrano-rbenv` plugin does it [here](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake#L44).

Here's how that would look in your case:

```
set :optional_var, fetch(:optional_var, 'optional value')
```

Second argument to `fetch` method is the default value.

Comment: Simple and elegant. I was so fixated on using conditional logic that it didn't occur to me to check the fetch() function. Tested this, and it looks like it works perfectly. Cheers!